# PMD error - AvoidThrowingRawExceptionTypes

Tags: java, exception, pmd

I have a class as follows, when I run PMD rule I'm getting a PMD Alert of type `AvoidThrowingRawExceptionTypes`. I'm not able to resolve this, because when I add any other exception types in constructor throws clause I'm getting error in

```
new PersistenceManager(CommonConstants.IP_DB)
```

How to resolve this? Can anybody help me on this?.

```
public class PersistenceManager implements CommonConstants {
.....

/**
     * Stores the persistence mgr for IPMasterData_DB
     */
    public static PersistenceManager IPMasterData_DB  = new PersistenceManager(
                                                              CommonConstants.IP_DB);
     /**
             * Configures the data source according to the resource passed.
             * 
             * @param dbName
             *        Databasename
             */
            protected PersistenceManager(String dbName) throws Exception{
                String resourceName = "";
                if (LOGGER == null) {
                    LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PersistenceManager.class);
                }
                try {

                    resourceName = getConfigFileName(dbName);

                    this.sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(resourceName)
                            .setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size",
                                    PersistenceManager.getBatchSize(dbName))
                            .buildSessionFactory();
                } catch (HibernateException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    LOGGER
                            .error("Exception building SessionFactory for configKey ",
                                    ex);
                    throw new RuntimeException(ErrorConstants.SESSIONFACTORY_BUILD, ex);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: PMD just saying that it's error prone habit to throw RAW exceptions. You could remove specification about throwing exceptions since your constructor throws only `RuntimeException`. But there are still open questions about design: 1) is hibernate exception is really rare and unexpected, 2) if state of could be repaired after this error

Answer (score 4):

It is a good programming practice to throw specialized exceptions rather than generic exceptions. `PMD` can detect and advise you on this and this is exactly what has been done.

Wrap your exceptions in a specialized exception and throw it rather than throwing an instance of `RuntimeException`.

Comment: As author said - he gets compilation errors in Singelton initialization (we all know that singeltons could be real evil)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, PMD criticizes not the throws clause but `throw new RuntimeException(..`. You can let the throws clause as is but throw a new (more specific) RuntimeException.

Answer (score 0):

PMD refers to Programming Mistakes Detector.
It a good practice is java to throw the specific error/exception rather than throwing the generic/general exception.

Eg- ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is a subclass of RuntimeException in java. If you know that your code may throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at some point, it is excepted that you must throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException instead of general exception which is -RuntimeException.